# Regex? Match part of or whole word

Tags: python, regex

I was wondering if it's possible to use regex with python to capture a word, or a part of the word (if it's at the end of the string).

Eg:
target word - potato
string - "this is a sentence about a **potato**"
string - "this is a sentence about a **potat**"
string - "this is another sentence about a **pota**"

Thanks!

Comment: The question implies that you want to also match `'my potato is brown'` but not `'my pot is brown'`.  In other words, partial matches are only allowed at the end of the string. Is that correct?

Comment: yep that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

def get_matcher(word, minchars):
    reg = '|'.join([word[0:i] for i in range(len(word), minchars - 1, -1)])
    return re.compile('(%s)$' % (reg))

matcher = get_matcher('potato', 4)
for s in ["this is a sentence about a potato", "this is a sentence about a potat", "this is another sentence about a pota"]:
    print matcher.search(s).groups()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
('potato',)
('potat',)
('pota',)
```

Comment: A couple comments, `word[:i]` is the same as `word[0:i]` but more commonly used.  You can drop the `[]` to turn the list-comp into a generator expression.  (`join` won't care).  You might want to `re.escape(word[0:i])`

Comment: You can use `'|'.join(itertools.accumulate(word)).join('()')` if you want to build the regex with a generator.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know how to match a regex in python, but the regex would be:

```
"\bp$|\bpo$|\bpot$|\bpota$|\bpotat$|\bpotato$"
```

This would match anything from `p` to `potato` if its the last word in the string, and also for example not something like "foopotato", if this is what you want.

The `|` denotes an alternative, the `\b` is a "word boundary", so it matches a position (not a character) between a word- and a non-word character. And the `$` matches the end of the string (also a position).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$` to match at the end of a string.  For example, the following would match 'potato' only at the end of a string (first example):

```
"potato$"
```

This would match all of your examples:

```
"pota[to]{1,2}$"
```

However, some risk of also matching "potao" or "potaot".

Comment: OP also wants to match part of the word. So he wants to match all the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
patt = re.compile(r'(p|po|pot|pota|potat|potato)$')
patt.search(string)
```

I was tempted to use `r'po?t?a?t?o?$'`, but that would also match **poto** or **pott**.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with a regex as far as I know, without pointless `(p|po|pot ...)` matches which are excessive. Instead, just pick off the last word, and match that using a substring:

```
match = re.search('\S+$', haystack)
if match.group(0) == needle[:len(match.group(0))]:
    # matches.
```