# regex match partial or whole word

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to figure out a regular expression which can match either the whole word or a (predefined in length, e.g first 4 chars) part of the word.

For example, if I am trying to match the word `between` and my offset is set to `4`, then

> between betwee betwe betw

are matches, but not the

> bet betweenx bet12 betw123 beta

I have created an example in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6pG3/1), where I am trying (with no luck) a combination of positive lookahead `(?=)` and a non-word boundary `\B`.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13405223/2279200) which proposes a word around in its accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405331/2279200). <s>As I understand, it overrides the matcher somehow, to run all the possible regular expressions, based on the word and an offset.</s>

My code has to be written in C#, so I am trying to convert the aforementioned code. <s>As I see `Regex.Replace` (and I assume `Regex.Match` also) can accept delegates to override the default functionality,</s> but I can not make it work.

Comment: For between, try `\b(betw)(?:e{1,2}n?)?\b`

Comment: @SebastianProske, That works, let me see if based on that I can achieve something 'more dynamic'

Comment: `\babcd(?:e(?:f(?:gh?))?)?\b` would be a more general pattern, that you could try to build automatically (matching `abcdefgh` with at least 4 letters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the first 4 characters, and make the remaining ones optional.
Then wrap these in word boundaries and parenthesis.

So in the case of "between", it would be

```
@"\b(betw)(?:(e|ee|een)?)\b"
```

The code to achieve that would be:

```
public string createRegex(string word, int count)
{
    var mandatory = word.Substring(0, count);
    var optional = "(" + String.Join("|", Enumerable.Range(1, count - 1).Select(i => word.Substring(count, i))) + ")?";
    var regex = @"\b(" + mandatory + ")(?:" + optional + @")\b";
    return regex;
}
```

Comment: @bobblebubble right, thanks for pointing that out, didn't even think about that case. Its corrected now.

Comment: I like how you create an 'easy to read' version of the expression (which a novice like me can understand), however I will accept Phate01's answer since it is more compact.

Comment: @Athafoud Phate01's method creates a pattern (for your example) that also matches "bet111", should that be the case?

Comment: Nice catch! I do not want to match cases like `bet111`

Comment: I think I also caught a bug in you code, the `Enumerable.Range(1, count - 1)` is better to change to `Enumerable.Range(1, word.Length - count)`

Answer (score 1):

The code in the answer you mentioned simply builds up this:

```
betw|betwe|betwee|between
```

So all you need is to write a function, to build up a string with a substrings of given word given minimum length.

```
static String BuildRegex(String word, int min_len)
    {
        String toReturn = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.Length - min_len +1; i++)
        {
            toReturn += word.Substring(0, min_len+i);
            toReturn += "|";
        }

        toReturn = toReturn.Substring(0, toReturn.Length-1);

        return toReturn;
    }
```

[Demo](http://goo.gl/VfQiDW)

Comment: As soon as I understand what the code, I came up with a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
\b(bet(?:[^\s]){1,4})\b
```

And replace `bet` and the `4` dynamically like this:

```
public static string CreateRegex(string word, int minLen)
{
    string token = word.Substring(0, minLen - 1);
    string pattern = @"\b(" + token + @"(?:[^\s]){1," + minLen + @"})\b";

    return pattern;
}
```

Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/lH0oL2/1

EDIT: as for the `bet1122` match, you can edit the pattern this way:

```
\b(bet(?:[^\s0-9]){1,4})\b
```

If you don't want to match some chars, just enqueue them into the [] character class.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lH0oL2/2
For more info, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: As @Domysee pointed, your answer wrongly matches cases like `bet12`, `betw123` and `beta`

Comment: @Athafoud the fix is really simple, I updated my question

Comment: I tried the exact same, however as I wrote in previous comment, `beta`, is also a mis-match. So in order to catch the word I want, I have to 'exclude' every char or symbols NOT IN {w, we, wee, ween }

Comment: True I didn't see that. Glad that you solved your problem!